# fetch 5 items for each day in a given month, in raw sql or Django orm

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql

Suppose an event is associated with a date.

For a given month,

I'd like to retrieve events happening in that month,
with a constraint such that:
I want only 5 events at max for each day.

Comment: Please tag your question with the underlying database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions.  So, this would be written as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by thedate
                                order by thedate) as seqnum
      from t
      where date >= @date1 and date < @date2
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5
```

`@date1` and `@date2` are just place holders for the values that define the beginning and end of the period you care about.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I'm not familiar with row_number and looking up what it means. Just checking, the `seqnum <=10` doesn't mean partitions with less than 10 members? I want max 10 members (events) even for the date with more than 10 members.

Comment: oh nvm, I get it. it returns members who are tagged with less than 5, so it's first 5 members.. Thanks I get it.